# lsnrctl doesn't work on Oracle 11gR2 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener, ubuntu-16.04

`lsnrctl` `start` `stop` and `status` do absolutely nothing

```
oracle@acer-Aspire-7730G:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin$ lsnrctl start
oracle@acer-Aspire-7730G:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin$ lsnrctl status
oracle@acer-Aspire-7730G:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin$ lsnrctl stop
```

LISTENER seems to start only when i create it or reconfigure it from netca and i get that message:

> Oracle Net Listener Startup:
>       Running Listener Control: 
>         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER
>       Listener Control complete.
>       Listener started successfully. Oracle Net Services configuration successful. The exit code is 0

But if i try `lsnrctl status` i don't get nothing and when i am trying to create a db says that no LISTENER had started.

My /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       acer-Aspire-7730G

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My sqlnet.ora :

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhom$
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)

ADR_BASE = /u01/app/oracle
```

My listener.ora :

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbh$
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

for some reason i don't see any tnsnames.ora file

`which lsnrctl` shows `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl`
`echo $TNS_ADMIN` doesn't show anything

I have also tried changing permissions on /tmp/.oracle but nothing changed.

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

gives me correctly `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`

also `echo $PATH` gives me correctly

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

My bash is :

```
# Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=SID; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64; export LD_LIBRARY_$
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

lsnrctl permissions are

```
ls -lah lsnrctl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall 0 Αύγ  15  2009 lsnrctl
```

Seems to has 0 bytes for some reason.

Input of `chmod 755 lsnrctl` and `chmod +x lsnrctl` make no difference.

I can connect to sqlplus, but not from browser on localhost. I have tried and reinstalling the oracle but no difference.

Comment: When you installed Oracle, or f you reinstalled or [relinked the binaries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/cnfg_prd.htm#UNXAR154), did you get linker errors?

Comment: Yes the first error i get is the "Error in invoking target install of makefile ins_ctx.mk" but also what i've tried from searching didn't changed it. So i just ignored it.

Comment: Look at [My Oracle Support note 362285.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=362285.1).